# Delaying multiple jQuery objects with same class but different id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to achieve an effect similar to the one seen in [this][1] page

[1]: http://imgmodels.com/results.aspx?cityID=1&catID=1&subid=1767 where the elements of each column are loaded at different times. I tried the following approach

```
    function setDelay(name, modulus){
            var numberString = name.substring(2);
            var number = parseFloat(numberString);
            var delay = number%modulus * 1000;
            alert(delay);
            return delay;
     }; 
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    var visible=new Boolean(0);
                    $("h1").click(function (){
                        //alert ("you click");
                    if(visible==0) {
                            $(".imgDefault").delay(setDelay($(".imgDefault").attr('id'),$(".imgDefault").parent().parent().attr('id'))).animate(
                        {'width':'150px'
                        },1000);
                        visible = 1;
    } else {
        $(".imgDefault").animate(
                        {'width':'0px'
                        },1000);
                        visible = 0;

    }
}); //ends .click eventHandler
    });// ends document ready function
//JavaScript Document
```

then the html looks as follows where I programatically create various image(in this code the source is the same but will change later on)

```
            <?php include 'header.php';

            function imageArray($size){
                $limit = $size;
                $imagesPerRow = 6;
                echo "<div id='". $imagesPerRow ."'>";
                echo "<h1>click me</h1>";

                for($i=1; $i<=$limit; $i++) { //willCreate an image container and display the image with the width reduced to 0
                    echo ("
                    <div class='fixedWidth'>
                        <img src='001/display.png'  id='id" . $i . "' class='imgDefault' width='150' height='185' />
                    </div>
                    ");
                } //ends for
                echo "</div>";
            } //ends imageArray()
            $numberOfImages = 23;
            imageArray($numberOfImages);
            include 'footer.php'; ?>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/animate2.js"></script>
```

The problem is that jQuery apparently doesn't work the way I'm thinking it should and the code isn't working. I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve my code so it does what I want.
Thanks. Hope it is clear what I'm trying to do, if not, I'll be happy to edit.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: @dreamweiver Your edit was invalid I had to roll it back. "programmatically" != "grammatically"

Comment: @BleedingFingers: sorry typically typo.

Comment: @Jupiter: could you create jsfiddle,may be we can tune it there , http://jsfiddle.net